# How do I remove ASCII "Null" from a Microsoft Word 2010 document?

Tags: microsoft-word, search, microsoft-word-2010

I have OCRed a document. The OCR software has created lots of NULL characters in the finalized Word 2010 document. I know that because I have found this [converter](http://easycalculation.com/ascii-hex.php), which has transformed one of the questionable strings into `122 117 110 101 104 NULL 32 109 101 110 100`).

I have a few search-and-replace operations I'd like to perform. Null prevents me from doing this.

How do I find all NULL characters in from this document?

Tried so far in the "Search" field:

- ^NULL
- ^000 (ASCII)
- ^u0, ^u00, ^u000, ^u0000 (Unicode)

I don't mind if the solution requires me to use OpenOffice/LibreOffice or VBA.

More about NUL:

- [How to Insert a Null Character (ASCII 00) in Notepad?](https://superuser.com/questions/61742/insert-a-null-character-ascii-00-in-notepad)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Unrelated questions:

- [How can I remove unicode characters in a Microsoft Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/365422/how-can-i-remove-unicode-characters-in-a-microsoft-word-document)

Comment: You could copy and paste the text to notepad. If the NULLs persist then use tr on the text document. (E.g. ` tr "0x000" " " to replace NULL with a white space).

Comment: @hennes What tool should I replace it with? How do I enter tr in Notepad?

Comment: Tr is a separate program (TRanslate). It should be installed by default on OS/X. If you are using windows instead you can download it from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/   But before you try it, first copy it from winword.exe, paste it to notepad and save it. That is probably enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out eventually.

NULL is `ad` in hexadecimal code (at least according to this website: http://www.string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx).

`ad`is `173` in unicode (according to here: http://easycalculation.com/hex-converter.php).

When I search in Word for `^u173`, it works like a charm.

Comment: Interesting, I get a ų when I enter this in my word 2010.

Comment: @MDMoore313 Funny, I get the same as you when I do a Unicode shortcut (Alt-X or Alt-C). But when I do a Alt+0173, I get NUL, which in Word displays similar to a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the `ALT` key, typing `255` on the number pad, and releasing the `ALT` key.

**Update**

Try this:

```
There is a symbol which looks like ...

N
U
L

... which is U+2400 (press and hold Alt while you type 9216 - or in recent 
versions of Word type 2400 and press Alt+X)
```

Taken from http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=78318. I can confirm it worked for me, but I don't know if this is they symbol your referring to.

Comment: 0xFF ('ÿ') is quite different than 0x00 (NUL).

Comment: Strange, everywhere else in windows it shows blank. This used to be the null in older versions.

Comment: Didn't work. But I found out eventually - posted my own answer. Thx for your trouble